# How to make an API call to a REST ws from an Alfresco workflow?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, alfresco

I have followed this tutorial: https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html
For now, I have created a *HelloWorld* workflow and deployed it successfully using **Alfresco Maven SDK** for *Alfresco 6.2*. This is the part of corresponding *.bpmn* file that prints *Hello World!* in server's log:

```
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="usertask1">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
                <activiti:field name="script">
                    <activiti:string>logger.log("Hello, World!");</activiti:string>
                </activiti:field>
            </activiti:executionListener>
        </extensionElements>
    </sequenceFlow>
```

However, I need to make an API call to https://google.com, just for testing purposes. But, when I try this:

```
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="usertask1">
        <extensionElements>
            <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.listener.ScriptExecutionListener">
                <activiti:field name="script">
                    <activiti:string>
                        var url = "https://google.com";
                        
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open("GET", url);
                        
                        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                           if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                              logger.log(xhr.status);
                              logger.log(xhr.responseText);
                           }};
                        
                        xhr.send();                 
                    </activiti:string>
                </activiti:field>
            </activiti:executionListener>
        </extensionElements>
    </sequenceFlow>
```

I get this exception:

```
org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 01030043 Failed to execute supplied script: 01030042 ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined. (AlfrescoJS#3)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeString(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:287)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeString(ScriptServiceImpl.java:293)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScriptString(ScriptServiceImpl.java:200)
```

Investigating, I checked this post: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/calling-rest-service-via-rule-script/td-p/32830.
It seems (from my understanding) that I need to make the API call using a Java class and then, somehow, invoke that object from js on the *.bpmn* file. So:

1. Could you please tell me where do I have to create this class in my Maven project? Is it a package? Could you tell me the exact steps on how to create it?
2. Could you paste here the exact code that implements this class?
3. Could you tell me how to invoke the java object from js in the *.bpmn* file?

**IMPORTANT:** I need to log the API Call response some way. It could be either log that you want, but I need to know if Google is answering me accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is a browser-specific function, you can't call it from Rhino server-side JS. IIRC you need to setup a Connector to the remote host in config, then use the Surf remote connector object to make the remote http request for you, something like https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/surf-connectors-endpoints.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedbak. However, I ask you: Where do I have to declare the connector? In the same .bpmn file? Can I make any operation with it beyond GET? How can I log the API call response somehow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, the allowed connectors in Alfresco are defined server-wide, partly for security. You define it in the config, then request the connector with that ID to do the fetching

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Excuse me for my insistance, but could you please tell me in what especific file do I have to declare the connector and how can I call it from the bpmn file? I tried it in a variety of forms and nothing works jeje

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a alfresco maven [project](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/maven-sdk/tutorial/tutorial.html). Then you have to create a java backed webscript by following the alfresco [docs](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-tutorials-java-backed.html).

Below is the example of the webscript desc.xml.

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>BPM Review</shortname>
  <description>Review and approve a BPM task</description>
  <url>/someco/bpm/review?id={idArgument}&amp;action={transArgument}</url>
  <format default="html">extension</format>
  <authentication runas="admin">guest</authentication>
  <transaction>required</transaction>
</webscript>



// Dependencies
    private WorkflowService workflowService;

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status) {
        
        final String id = req.getParameter("id");
        final String action = req.getParameter("action");

        if (id == null || action == null) {
            logger.debug("Email, ID, action, or secret not set");
            status.setCode(400);            
            status.setMessage("Required data has not been provided");
            status.setRedirect(true);
        }
        
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        logger.debug("About to update task, id:" + id + " with outcome:" + action);
        
        Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>();
        props.put(QName.createQName(SomeCoWorkflowModel.NAMESPACE_SOMECO_WORKFLOW_CONTENT_MODEL, SomeCoWorkflowModel.PROP_APPROVE_REJECT_OUTCOME), action);
        workflowService.updateTask(id, props, null, null);      
        workflowService.endTask(id, action);
        logger.debug("Task updated and ended.");    

        return model;
}
```

Then you can call the webscript anywhere as a Rest call like below.

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/someco/bpm/review?id=activiti$

Comment: Great! Excuse me, I am not a developer. Could you please tell me what is the exact code that I have to put on my bpmn file? Also, If I am not bothering you, could you please give me the java code to do exactly the API call that I want? Thanks in advance and excuse me for my bad english.